# Efficient way to add items of list to another list with a map

Tags: python, optimization

I have a two lists of floats L1, L2, or lengths a, b respectively. I also have a list F, of length a, whose values are integers of the range [-1,b-1]. I want to update L2 in the following way:

```py
for i in filter(lambda x: F[x]+1, range(len(F))):
    L2[F[i]] += L1[i]
```

Basically, F is a function of L1's index. For each index, i, of L1, if F[i] = -1, we do nothing, otherwise, we take L1's i-th item and add it to L2's F[i]-th item.

I am doing this in a program where the lengths of a and b will grow exponentially as I make my results more accurate. (also, F is roughly 50% -1's) I realize this already takes linear time, but I was wondering if there was some way to improve the constant faster, possibly through list/sum comprehension? Or, if I will need to know the contents of L2 after multiple updates, is there a practical way to store these updates, and do them all at once in a faster manner?

What about the case where I have two lists of lists LL1, LL2, each containing c lists of lengths a, and b respectively, with just one list/map F? If I want LL1[i] to update LL2[i] for all i in [0,c-1], is there a smart way to do this, or is there nothing better than doing each i one by one?

Clarification: converting to numpy structures is completely acceptable, I just lack prior-knowledge about how to utilize numpy efficiently.

Comment: consider vectorizing your code (i.e., use numpy). I'm pretty sure it will result in manifold speed improvement.

Comment: Can you use numpy? Or does this have to be pure-python?

Comment: numpy is fine, I am completely unfamiliar with what "manifold speed improvement" would mean though

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fairly efficient as is. The only improvement that can be made as far as I can see comes from avoiding using a lambda function, which increases overhead to call the function per iteration. Instead, you can use the `enumerate` function to generate indices and values of `F` to iterate over, and filter the value of `F` with a simple `if` statement:

```
for i, j in enumerate(F):
    if j != -1:
        L2[j] += L1[i]
```